# Удаление с пк приложение

Tags: python, pyqt

При нажатии на кнопку я удаляю приложение, но после выполнения выдает ошибку:

```
raise ProcessExecutionError(
plumbum.commands.processes.ProcessExecutionError: Unexpected exit code: 19
Command line: | 'C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\111.0.5563.65\Installer\setup.exe' --uninstall --channel=stable --system-level --verbose-logging /S
```

Код:

```
 def buttonSteamDel(self):
        for _ in winapps.search_installed('Google Chrome'):

            winapps.uninstall('Google Chrome', args=['/S'])

            icon1 = QtGui.QIcon()
            icon1.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(":/icon/image/icon/free-icon-download-545759.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Mode.Normal,
                            QtGui.QIcon.State.Off)
            self.pushDownloadGoogle.setIcon(icon1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Данная ошибка может быть вызвана из-за таких причин как:

- Для выполнения данного удаления у исполняемой программы нет прав Администратора
- Гугл Хром уже запущен на компьютере, либо его процессы.

Comment: Права администратора есть и гугл был везде закрыт. А также само удаление работает. Но после именно удаления ошибку выдает.